# Trouble with LINQ Join with multiple on conditions

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

I'm having difficulty working through this query in LINQ.

I have two POCO classes:

```
public class Student
{
  public int StudentID get/set
  // other stuff
}

public class UniversityClass
{
   public int ClassID get/set
   // other stuff
}
```

There are no navigation properties between these two tables. They exist essentially independent of one another. To manage which students are registered to which class and the status of that registration, I created an intermediary class/table `Registration`. `Registration` also has no navigation properties configuring any particular relationship between `Registration` -> `Student` or `Registration` and `UniversityClass`.

```
public class Registration
{
  public int Id get/set
  public string StudentID get/set
  public Student Student get/set
  public int ClassID get/set
  public UniversityClass Class get/set
  public int Status get/set
}
```

I have been using Registration.ClassID and Registration.StudentID as a sort of composite index to return a particular Registration record. Basically checking if a student is registered to that class.

What I've been attempting to do, and failing at, is a query that returns me all Students for a particular class with a Status of l (in reality, `Registration.Status` is an `Enum` with an integer value but for simplicity sake I'm just using an int property here.

When I open up SQL Server Management Studio, I seem to be able to write the query just fine and return the data I expect, but with EF Core and LINQ, I'm struggling. Any help? Do I need navigation properties?

Comment: You should not be using manual joins with EF. Why aren’t you using `Include` and/or Navigation Properties?

Comment: How would I filter students on the registration table then?

Comment: By using Navigation Properties in the query - however your posted code doesn't show the navigation properties, you just put "// other stuff", so **please post the full entity class definitions**; also please post your entity configuration code (e.g. `modelBuilder.Entity<T>.Property`). Do you have an existing DB design with the FK definitions? (I recommend avoiding "code-first" approaches: they really don't scale, instead design your database first (in SQL with hand-written `CREATE TABLE` statements) and then use EF Core's Scaffolding feature to generate classes instead of the other way around.

Comment: `and` is not a valid C# LINQ operator. Also the criteria  `r.ClassId = s.StudentID` makes no sense. Also `=` should be `==`. Also you should really be using navigation properties as mentioned by other comments. The `Student` class should have something like `public ICollection<Registration> Registrations { get; set; }` which you can use in query for filtering `_dbContext.Students.Where(s => s.Registrations.Any(r => r.Status == 1))` And inside `Any` you could add ` && r.ClassId == someClassId` if you need to filter by status and class. etc.

Comment: If you are looking for a list of students that are registered to any class then you should be able to just scan the Registrations table and filter out duplicate Student objects, something like `_dbContext.Registrations.Where(r => r.Status == 1).Select(r => r.Student).Distinct()`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you have a one-to-many relation between `Students` and `Registrations`: Every Student has zero or more Registrations, every Registration is a Registration of exactly one Student, the Student that the foreign key StudentId refers to.

> I need to return all Students, who have a Registration status of 1.

I don't see anything about the `UniversityClass` in your requirement. Why are you using it in your solution?

Whenever you have a one-to-many relation, like Customers with their zero or more Orders, UniversityClasses with their zero or more Students, or in your case Students with their Registrations, and you want "items with their sub-items", consider to start at the "one" side and use one of the overloads of [Queryable.GroupJoin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.groupjoin).

On the other hand, if you want sub-items, each sub-item with the one and only parent item that the foreign key refers to, use one of the overloads of [Queryable.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.join)

In your one-to-many relation, it might be that some Students don't have a Registration at all. Other Students might have several Registrations. What do you want with those Students?

It might be that you don't have a one-to-many relation, but a one-to-one relation: Every Student has exactly one Registration. When you ask your next question, consider to provide this important information.

> I need to return all Students, who have a Registration status of 1.

Do you only want Student properties, or do you also want some Properties of the Registration(s) of this Student?

```
// Get all students that have at least one Registration with Status 1
var studentsWithAtLeastOneRegistration1 = dbContext.Students.GroupJoin(
    dbContext.Registrations,

    student => student.StudentId,           // from every Student take the primary key
    registration => registration.StudentId, // from every Registration take the foreign key

    // parameter resultSelector: from every Student and all matching Registrations
    // make one new:
    (student, registrationsOfThisStudent) => new
    {
        // Select only the Student properties that you plan to use:
        StudentId = student.StudentId,
        ...

        Registrations = registrationsOfThisStudent.Select(registration => new
        {
            // Select only the RegistrationId that you plan to use:
            RegistrationId = registration.Id,
            Status = registration.Status,
            ...

            // do not Select StudentId, you already know the value
            // StudentId = registration.StudentId,
        })
        .ToList(),
})

// keep only those Students that have at least one Registration with proper Status
.Where(student => student.Registrations.Any(registration => registration.Status == 1));
```

Of if you only want Students that have only proper Registration Status:

```
// Get all students that have only Registrations with Status 1
var studentsWithAtLeastOneRegistration1 = dbContext.Students.GroupJoin(
   ...) // same as above

// keep only the Students where all Registrations have a Status 1:
.Where(student => student.Registrations.All(registration => registration.Status == 1));
```

Note: the result will also have Students that have no Registration at all. If you don't want them:

```
.Where(student => student.Registrations.Any()
       && student.Registrations.All(registration => registration.Status == 1));
```

Comment: Hm. I view it more as many to many. The combination of studentID and classID make a sort of composite key to discover if a student is registered to a specific class.

Comment: `GroupJoin` will fail with EF Core.

Comment: @Harald You really need to update your lectures for EF Core. For instance, `GroupJoin` is not supported since v3.0 and it's unknown if it will ever be supported. So speaking about it and suggesting it makes no sense since the people will get runtime exceptions if follow your advices. This is regarding `GroupJoin`. Navigation properties are ok of course. And in fact with navigation properties there is no need of `GroupJoin` or `Join`, so no need to explain them at all - these are basically for LINQ to Objects.